# Position div on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Ok, so I want to position on top of another div which has a background image. The image-div has the following properties:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url('../img/1.jpg');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

This looks like I want on all devices. But now I need to overlay the image-div with a clickable div that fits a certain part of the image. Getting the div to fit is easy, just set position to absolute and set top, left, width and height, but as soon as i display in another resolution/density the div is way off, no surprise there. So i tried with positioning by using % or vh and vw but nothing seems to work.

How would I go about positioning divs on top of the image regardless on what device, resolution and density I'm at?

Comment: Kindly, check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of `background-position`, `background-size` and an offset in percentages of the containing div.

Keep the `background-position` at a certain value so the spot on the image is always in screen.
Use `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` to keep the image (or it's container) responsive.
If you have two or more spots on the outer edges of the image I suggest using `contain`, but this will reduce the image size considerably on smaller screens while your inner div will stay reasonably large.
In other cases, use `cover` for resize purposes.

Here I created an example: (I used Jquery UI to make the image resizable)

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
```

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465218550585-6d069382d2a9?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=994&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}
.hit-me-container {
  height: 16px;
  left: 52%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 16px;
}
.hit-me {
  animation: pulse 1s ease infinite;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.hit-me-container:hover:after {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  content: 'Buy these glasses';
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: -4px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="resizable">
  <div class="hit-me-container">
    <div class="hit-me"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcsd6vwg/1/)

Comment: Not bad! I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #div_1
        {
            position:relative;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:200px;
            background-image: url('../img/1.jpg');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
        }
    #div_2
        {
            position:absolute;
            width:50%;
            height:60%;
            margin:0px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="div_1">
        <div id="div_2">
            testing...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this will make the overlay same size as the image, I only want to overlay a certain part of the image where i need it to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` inside of the `div` with the `background-image`, but then position it within the div wherever you want using `%`s, not `px` or absolute values.

```css
#bg{
position: relative;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image: url('/favicon.ico');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
  z-index: 5
  }
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 13%;
  left: 34%
}
#overlay:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50,50,200,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this out. It kind of works but it seems to give me problems when width height ration changes..

Comment: set height width ratio to a certain amount?